# Как лучше добавлять токены в программу (на Python)?

Tags: python, безопасность

Чтобы не светить токен при открытии доступа к программе, его не пишут в коде напрямую. Отсюда вопрос: как лучше его добавлять? Через файл? Подключать как библиотеку? Ещё как-то?
Мне способ с библиотекой кажется наиболее удобным, но я чаще встречаю считывание из файла. Или это не принципиально?

Answer (score 3):

Если вы собираетесь публиковать свой код на GitHub или на другом ресурсе, можете вынести токен в отдельный файл, который публиковать не будете, или же просто перед публикацией заменить этот токен на что-нибудь другое (например, сделать эту строку пустым, указав в комментарии, что в это место надо вставить токен).

Если вы во время разработки делали коммиты с токеном, его можно будет удалить из истории репозитория. Подробнее см. [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history). Тем не менее я не рекомендую делать коммиты с токеном даже на локальном репозитории, так как при публикации о сохранившихся в истории токенах можно невзначай забыть.

Answer (score 2):

Есть практика хранения токенов/учёток и других конфеденциальных данных в переменных окружения и обращаться к ним из кода через os.environ['variable_name']. Это достаточно удобно и работает под win и linux как в системном так и виртуальном окружении.